# How to stop the background image of a UIButton from affecting its intrinsicContentSize?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a huge image with size 1095x726 points.

I have set this image as the background image of a `UIButton`. This has caused the button to increase in size. I observe that the `intrinsicContentSize` of the button is equal to the size of the background image.

I would like if the size of the button is not determined by the background image.

The size of the button should be as if it has no background image. The background image should adjust to the size of the button and not the other way around.

Can anyone point out how to make the `intrinsicContentSize` of a `UIButton` not depend on its background image?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set any constraints for your UIButton?

If not, you have to set all the needed constraints (width, height, position inside your controller).

Comment: The constraints have been added to set the position of the UIButton. However, constraints have not been added to set the width and height of the UIButton. If the width and height of the button have not been set then it will take the width and height of the intrinsicContentSize of the UIButton.

Answer (score 0):

I subclassed `UIButton` and overrode `intrinsicContentSize`. It does not handle all the cases but is sufficient for my purpose.

```swift
class TitleFittingButton: UIButton {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        var titleSize = titleLabel?.intrinsicContentSize ?? .zero
        titleSize.width += titleEdgeInsets.left + titleEdgeInsets.right
        titleSize.height += titleEdgeInsets.top + titleEdgeInsets.bottom
        return titleSize
    }
}
```